# Where to find designers for independent projects?

Tags: game-design, project-management, assets, human-resources

Let's say I'm a programmer, I know some artists, we've got a game engine and fun prototype done, and we're ready to enter the indie equivalent of "production".

But the game is full of "programmer design" (and/or "artist design"). We've got a core design concept, but average level design, average AI patterns, average writing, poor balance here and there.

Other questions have covered how to help independent developers find programmers and artists. Where can independent artists and programmers find *designers*? People who can refine and extend the design elements of the game until they really stand out.

Answer (score 5):

http://forums.indiegamer.com is a great forum for finding help. There's a "Help Wanted" section but they allow only paid offers.

Comment: +1 because it looks like a high S:N ratio, but it looks like the standard "I'm an artist, I need a programmer" / "I'm a programmer, I need an artist" requests.

Comment: It's kinda ironic "indiependant" but paid. Most of the Indie Dev Teams I know were founded on non-paid base, but anyways... :)

Comment: It depends on your definition of Indie. Independent means not being funded by publisher, thus independent to do anything it wants (instead of what the publisher wants). Technically even Valve is independent.

Answer (score 3):

The [ModDB & IndieDB forums](http://www.indiedb.com/forum) have a [Recruiting & Resumes section](http://www.indiedb.com/forum/board/recruiting-resumes) where you can look for designers, artists, and programmers alike. ModDB and IndieDB have the added benefit of allowing you to create a showcase page for your project, where you can attract fans and potential team members.

Answer (score 2):

ModDB and IndieDB also have an [official jobs board](http://www.indiedb.com/jobs) which is free to post on.